# export doesn't work in a background process

Tags: bash, shell

**pipe.sh**

```
 export START=100
 . ./other.sh &
 wait
```

**other.sh**

```
sleep 5
export END=200
```

But I don't see the variable **END** in `export -p`. If I source **other.sh** in the foreground it works though.

```
 export START=100
 . ./other.sh
```

How do I export variables from background process? Any work arounds?

Comment: How do you expect sourcing in the background to work? I can imagine two scenarios, neither of which is useful (parent detaches from background process immediately when it is spawned; or, parent executes background commands at random times in between foreground commands). What are you trying to accomplish, and how does backround processing further that goal?

Comment: I am trying to find how much it takes to complete the back ground process. I have more than 10 different processes started at same time and running in the back ground. So I thought this way will be good to time the processes. I am open to any other ways. THanks.

Comment: Timing a background process is easy. Why do you need for it to export something back to the parent?

Comment: can you please suggest me a way for timing in a better way? I tried searching online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A child process cannot change parents environment, you need to declare the variable from the parent somehow. For example using a file:

pipe.sh:

```
export START=100
. ./other.sh > tmp &
wait
source tmp
rm tmp 
echo $END
```

other.sh:

```
sleep 5
echo "export END=200"
```

[Also see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6537624/390913).

Comment: I got it. Child process. Din strike me. Thanks.