# How do I capture output from a running process in a bash variable

Tags: swift, bash

I have a Swift command line program which is running a server and prints the URL of the server when it starts. I'm then trying capture the URL in a bash shell variable so I can pass it to other programs.

Basically my Swift program looks like this

```swift
@main
struct MyApplication {
    static func main() throws {
        let server = try VoodooServer {
            Endpoints.config
        }
        print(server.url.absoluteString)
        server.wait()
    }
}
```

and when I run it from the command line I get output that looks like this:

```bash
% .build/release/server run -c Tests/files/TestConfig3
http://127.0.0.1:8082
```

However when I try to capture the URL using

```bash
% export SERVER_URL=`.build/release/server run -c Tests/files/TestConfig3` &
[3] 19101
```

and then check the exported variables using `export` there's nothing there.

I've tried commenting out the `wait()` function so the server exits immediately and I get the URL in the variable. ie. running

```bash
% export SERVER_URL=`.build/release/server run -c Tests/files/TestConfig3`
% echo $SERVER_URL
http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

So I'm guessing the problem is that because the server is not exiting, the value is not being stored because stdout has not finished or something like that.

So how can I capture the output from the server into a variable without stopping it?

Comment: This question can be generalized to how to capture the first line of output to a variable from a never ending Unix process. It's not really specific to a Swift program. Given this, you might have better luck over at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). You may likely find an existing answer there. If not and you post a question there, I'd leave out the details of the Swift program and just mention you have a command line program that doesn't terminate but you need to get its first (and maybe only) line of output.

Comment: A child process cannot change the environment of its parent [export doesn't work in a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12324033/3422102)

Comment: Is it an option to tee the output of the command to a file (| tee /tmp/file), and in different process export the value from the file into the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the usage of `&`:

```
$ export HELLO=`echo world` &
[1] 3774017
[1]+  Done                    export HELLO=`echo world`
$ export | grep HELLO
$ export HELLO=`echo world` 
$ export | grep HELLO
declare -x HELLO="world"
```

When you run a command "regularly", the shell just runs it as you would expect. Examples of regular running:

```
echo world
.build/release/server run -c Tests/files/TestConfig3
export HELLO=`echo world`
export SERVER_URL=`.build/release/server run -c Tests/files/TestConfig3`
```

When you run things with `&`, you're asking the shell to run them in the background, while you continue about your day.
That means that your shell has to continue accepting your command, but also run the background command.
So the shell launches a background shell where it runs your commands. Meaning, when you run:

```
export SERVER_URL=`.build/release/server run -c Tests/files/TestConfig3` &
```

The shell launches a background shell, and the background shell runs:

```
export SERVER_URL=`.build/release/server run -c Tests/files/TestConfig3`
```

That background shell will indeed export `SERVER_URL` to its own subprocesses, but your regular, foreground shell, isn't a subprocess of the background shell. Rather, the background shell is a subprocess of the foreground shell.
That is why the export isn't visible in the foreground shell.

---

Unfortunately, there's no simple way to capture that URL while the server is still running. What people usually do is have the server write that information to a file, so that the foreground shell can read the file, e.g.:

```
$ ( (sleep 1; echo world > config; sleep 50) & ) &
[1] 3775004
[1]+  Done                    ( ( sleep 1; echo world > config; sleep 50 ) & )
$ sleep 1
$ export HELLO=`cat config`
$ export | grep HELLO
declare -x HELLO="world"
```

(I have replaced your Swift server with a simple bash command that goes to the background via fancy bash syntax)

As you can see, the background process writes its configuration to the file `config`, but it's difficult to know when `config` will be written, so you have to resort to something more complex:

```
$ ( (sleep 10; echo world > config.tmp; mv config.tmp config; sleep 50) & ) 
&
[1] 3775481
[1]+  Done                    ( ( sleep 10; echo world > config.tmp; mv config.tmp config; sleep 50 ) & )
$ while ! [ -f config ]; do sleep 1; done
$ export HELLO=`cat config`
$ export | grep HELLO
declare -x HELLO="world"
```

Here, we're writing to `config.tmp`, and we're only renaming it to `config` after we finish, to ensure that when the foreground shell tries to read, it reads the full configuration after the server definitely finished writing it.
But on the foreground side, we actually have to wait for it to finish writing it, which is what the `while` loop is for.