# bash background process modify global variable

Tags: bash, variables, background, subprocess, global

In my Bash script, I have a global variable `foo` set to some value and a function process `back_func` that is run in the background. I would like the background process to be able to access `foo` and modify its value, so that the change can be seen by the main process.

My script is structured in the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash
foo=0

function back_func {
     foo=$(($foo+1))
     echo "back $foo"
}

(back_func) &
echo "global $foo"
```

The output of the above script is

```
global 0
back 1
```

How can I get the `global` and `back` lines to both end with `1`? In other words, how can I make background process’s modification of `foo` be picked up by the main process?

Comment: Is the "main process" another bash script? Does it restart periodically?

Comment: what is the motivation for using an environment variable? The transport of the information could IMHO be done via a file which is much simpler to share.

Comment: @ct_ Yes the main process is another periodically running bash script.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl There are actually many such kind of vars, if for each var we create a file for sharing its value, it would be more complicate to manage the whole program. But for small size of program it's a nice idea to share values via file.

Comment: @algosolo OK. If the main process (let's call it _main.sh_) is another periodically running bash script then you could simply have the the other script (let's call it _other.sh_) write the value to a file (let's call this file _value.sh_).  

`**other.sh**`
`#! /bin/bash`
`echo "SOME_VAR=42" > /tmp/value.sh`  
  
`**main.sh**`  
`#! /bin/bash`  
`. /tmp/other.sh`
`# Now SOME_VAR will be set`

Comment: These threads might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537231/simple-background-process-question-in-bash and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324033/export-doesnt-work-for-a-back-ground-process?lq=1

Comment: @ct_ thanks for the answer, it seems that using a tmp file is a   clear solution so far.

Comment: @doubleDown is there anyway that I can return a value from the subprocess to the main process? like ret=(back_func)&; echo $ret

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Upgrade 2019

Playing with `bash_ipc_demo` adding completion and a graph generator.

### *Rendez-vous*

If you wanna have two independant process which could communicate, you have to place a *rendez-vous* somewhere both process can reach.

This could be a simple file, a fifo pipe, a unix socket, a TCP socket or maybe else (Rexx port).

### [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and other [shell](/questions/tagged/shell)

Bash don't have a equivalent to rexx port, so there is a little sample, using a rendez-vous file, that work (on my Linux).

I'm using *shared memory* `/dev/shm`, to reduce disk load.

#### Simple counter sample

```
$ back_func() {
    while :;do
        echo $(($(</dev/shm/foo)+1)) >/dev/shm/foo;
        sleep .3;
      done;
}
```

Let play

```
$ echo 1 >/dev/shm/foo
$ back_func &

$ echo $(</dev/shm/foo)
4

$ echo $(</dev/shm/foo)
21
```

Than stop now:

```
$ fg
back_func
^C
```

or

```
$ kill $!
$
[1]+  Terminated              back_func
```

#### More than one variables

For having many vars, there could by a nice manner:

```
$ back_func() {
    declare -A MYGLOBAL
    local vars
    while :; do
        ((MYGLOBAL["counter"]++))
        IFS=\ / read -a vars <<< "$(</proc/uptime) $(</proc/loadavg)"
        MYGLOBAL["uptime"]=$vars
        MYGLOBAL["idle"]=${vars[1]}
        MYGLOBAL["l01m"]=${vars[2]}
        MYGLOBAL["l05m"]=${vars[3]}
        MYGLOBAL["l15m"]=${vars[4]}
        MYGLOBAL["active"]=${vars[5]}
        MYGLOBAL["procs"]=${vars[6]}
        MYGLOBAL["lpid"]=${vars[7]}
        MYGLOBAL["rand"]=$RANDOM
        MYGLOBAL["crt"]=$SECONDS
        declare -p MYGLOBAL > /dev/shm/foo
        sleep 1
    done
}
```

Then

```
$ back_func &
[1] 27429
$ . /dev/shm/foo
$ echo ${MYGLOBAL['counter']}
5
$ echo ${MYGLOBAL['lpid']}
27432
```

and from there, why not:

```
$ dumpMyGlobal() {
    . /dev/shm/foo
    printf "%8s " ${!MYGLOBAL[@]}
    echo
    printf "%8s " ${MYGLOBAL[@]}
    echo
}

$ dumpMyGlobal
    l15m   uptime      crt    procs     lpid   active     rand     idle     l05m
  counter     l01m 
    0.42 13815568.06       95      554      649        1    31135 21437004.95   
  0.38       73     0.50 
$ dumpMyGlobal
    l15m   uptime      crt    procs     lpid   active     rand     idle     l05m
  counter     l01m 
    0.41 13815593.29      120      553      727        2     3849 21437046.41   
  0.35       98     0.33
```

or

```
$ dumpMyGlobal() {
    . /dev/shm/foo
    sort <(
        paste <(
            printf "%-12s\n" ${!MYGLOBAL[@]}
          ) <(printf "%s\n" ${MYGLOBAL[@]})
    )
}

$ dumpMyGlobal
active              1
counter             297
crt                 337
idle                21435798.86
l01m                0.40
l05m                0.44
l15m                0.45
lpid                30418
procs               553
rand                7328
uptime              13814820.80
```

#### Get variable with snapshot

and finally `getMyGlobalVar` function

```
$ declare -A MYGLOBALLOCK   # snapshot variable
$ getMyGlobalVar () { 
    local i sync=false
    [ "$1" == "--sync" ] && shift && sync=true
    if [ -z "${MYGLOBALLOCK[*]}" ] || $sync; then
        . /dev/shm/foo
        for i in ${!MYGLOBAL[@]}
        do
            MYGLOBALLOCK[$i]=${MYGLOBAL[$i]}
        done
    fi
    echo ${MYGLOBALLOCK[$1]}
}
```

will require `--sync` flag for re-reading *rendez-vous* in order to let you look about each fields from the same *snapshot*.

```
$ getMyGlobalVar --sync idle
362084.12

$ getMyGlobalVar idle
362084.12

$ getMyGlobalVar rand
1533

$ getMyGlobalVar rand
1533

$ getMyGlobalVar --sync rand
43256

$ getMyGlobalVar idle
362127.63
```

### Full useable demo:

There is a full sample: [bash_ipc_demo](http://f-hauri.ch/vrac/bash_ipc_demo.txt) or [bash_ipc_demo.shz](http://f-hauri.ch/vrac/bash_ipc_demo.shz.txt)

You could use by:

```
wget http://f-hauri.ch/vrac/bash_ipc_demo

source bash_ipc_demo
back_func help
Usage: back_func [-q] [start [-g N]|stop|restart|status|get|dump|help]
   -q    Quiet
   -g N  Start daemon, setting uptime_useGraph to N values

back_func status
Background loop function is not running.

back_func start -g 3600

back_func status
Background loop function (19939) is running.
```

From there, if you `source bash_ipc_demo` in another terminal, you could do the list into them.

You could even close the first terminal.

```
back_func dump
backFunc_count                     13
backFunc_now      2016-04-06 17:03:19
backFunc_pid                    19939
backFunc_running                  yes
backFunc_start    2016-04-06 17:03:07
cpu_numcores                        2
loadavg_15min                    0.44
loadavg_1min                     0.66
loadavg_5min                     0.54
loadavg_active                      1
loadavg_last_pid                20005
loadavg_process                   650
random                        3714432
uptime_graph_val                 3600
uptime_idle                 425499.43
uptime_up                   495423.53
uptime_usage1sec                 9.90
uptime_usage                    57.06
uptime_useGraph  57.06 8.91 7.50 6.93 12.00 9.41 7.84 9.90 7.50 11.88 7.92 9.31 
9.90
```

Then, you could get one value

```
back_func get backFunc_pid newVar
echo $newVar 
19939
```

or build a *quick cpu* graph:

```
lastMinuteGraph -p -o /tmp/lastMinuteGraph.png -W 640 -H 220
```

This will render a 640x220 PNG graphic, with `uptime_graph_val` values.
In this case, as `back_func start` was invoked with `-g 3600` from more
than one hour, graphic show 3600 peek on 640 columns and 0-100% on 220 lines:

[image: LastHourGraph]

(*Nota:* Command was originaly named `lastMinuteGraph` as 1st version of this just stored 60 values, now this use *`uptime_graph_val`* for number of values to store. As I've used `-g 3600` argument, this command could by named `lastHourGraph`).

Then:

```
back_func stop  
back_func get backFunc_end
2019-01-02 16:35:00
```

Comment: For fun, there is a [***compressed bash source file***](http://f-hauri.ch/vrac/bash_ipc_demo.shz.txt)

Comment: On my site: [bash_ipc_demo-v2.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/bash_ipc_demo-v2.sh.txt) ] More efficient, with some features and bash completion!

Answer (score 12):

According to the Bash manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists),

> If a command is terminated by the control operator ‘&’, the shell executes the command asynchronously in a subshell.

And since a process run in a subshell cannot modify the environment of the parent shell, I guess what you are trying to do is only possible via temp files / named pipes. Or you could rethink your approach.

Answer (score 4):

If the main process (let's call it main.sh) is another periodically running bash script then you could simply have the the other script (let's call it other.sh) write the value to a file (let's call this file value.sh).

**other.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash  
echo "SOME_VAR=42" > /tmp/value.sh
```

**main.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash  
. /tmp/value.sh  
# Now you can use SOME_VAR
```

Comment: Without locking, there's some risk to this: `>/tmp/value.sh` truncates the output file *before* `echo` writes to it, so there's a time window in which it's empty and then partially written. If you wanted a sure thing, you should use `flock` to grab a read lock before sourcing the file, and a write lock before modifying it.