# BASH local and flock

Tags: bash, local, flock

I try to use a flock like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/169969
but within a function ... and I try to update a local variable (locale to the function) from within the flock part, but it seems not update ...

## cat test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

function _job_worker()
{
        local z=1
        local result=


        (
                # Wait for lock on /var/lock/.manager.exclusivelock (fd 200)
                flock -x -w 10 200 || return

                z=2
                echo "slot equal $z"

        ) 200>/var/lock/.manager.exclusivelock

        echo "slot equal $z"

}

_job_worker
```

## ./test.sh

```
slot equal 2
slot equal 1
```

what the heck am I doing wrong ....

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `function` keyword -- it makes your scripts incompatible with POSIX sh, but adds no benefit in return for doing so.

Comment: you are right, thanks to point it out !

Comment: Of course, using `local` also makes the code incompatible with POSIX, but at least it adds some value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(` and `)` create a subshell. This is a separate process, with its own variables and state -- it's not just locals that don't escape a subshell, but global variables, file handles changes, current directory changes, and (pretty much) everything else.

Use `{` and `}` instead to create a block with scoped redirections running inside the same shell rather than starting a subshell.

That is:

```
_job_worker() {
        local z=1 result=
        {
                # Wait for lock on /var/lock/.manager.exclusivelock (fd 200)
                flock -x -w 10 200 || return
                z=2
                echo "slot equal $z"
        } 200>.manager.exclusivelock
        echo "slot equal $z"
}

_job_worker
```