# shell: race condition in assigning global variable

Tags: bash, shell, sh, race-condition

I am working on a script that goes:

```
#script_1.sh
function a() {
    export var1='...some calculations on $@...';
}

function b() {
    a "$@"
    local loc_b=$var1
}

function c() {
    a "$@"
    local loc_c=$var1
}

#script_2.sh
source script_1.sh
b val1 &
c val2 &
b val2 &
```

`function a` has `getopt` command and parses parameters for `b` and `c`. This has been simplified to a great extent.

When I call `function b`, `function c` and `function b` again at the end as background processes, I worry that I might have a race condition on assigning the `exported var1 variable` to the local variable.

1. If I can guarantee that calls to `function b` or `function c` will be as background processes, do I have to worry about the race condition here?
2. If there is no race, can I get away by not declaring the local variables for each function?

Comment: `export` doesn't do anything of value here: You can export values only to your children, not to your parent or your siblings. (A subshell that exports a value and then exits, then, simply throws that value away).

Comment: It's very tempting to flag this a duplicate of [bash background process modify global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207292/bash-background-process-modify-global-variable), insofar as the information conveyed in that question and its answers moots/conveys everything relevant here.

Comment: Great share. I have the concepts of `environment`, `subshell` and `globals` confused.
Correct me if this is wrong:
1. For a `function a` calling `function b`, we don't need to use `export` as it will be the same process.
2. `function a` called in background will inherit environment of it's parent (including all variables exported up to the function call).

Comment: Both (1) and (2) are correct. (And you don't even always need `export` for children -- a true subshell is a `fork()` with no `execve()`, but you only need to export a variable to put it in the environment if you need it to survive an `exec`-family call).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each background process gets its own copy of the environment. Child process can't change the environment of its parent process. So, there's no race condition: if you change a global variable before running a background process, the process will get the new value copied. If you run a background process before changing the value, the process will see the old value.

```
#!/bin/bash

global=1

inc () {
    ((++global))
    echo inc: $global
}

dec () {
    ((--global))
    echo dec: $global
}

inc & dec &
# 2   0

global=10
inc & dec & inc & dec &
# 11  9     11    9
```

Comment: Got it, this helps a lot. Thanks :)