# synchronize and limit the number of shell scripts running at the same time

Tags: linux, bash, posix, semaphore, flock

I'm looking for a way to synchronize some `bash` scripts on an Ubuntu environment so that no more than X scripts could run at the same time.

I've seen utilities like `flock`, however they don't grant the ability for more than one script to hold the lock.

I could think of several ways to implement this myself..

- get a hold of a lockfile, edit its content to mark the number of running scripts, then release it and lock again to reduce the number.
- create X lockfiles and attempt to lock any of them until succeed

But I would hope that someone already approached this problem and found a stable solution.

Comment: [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Comment: the scripts are being run by independent agents and therefore could not be synced on their initiation

Comment: @tripleee see my comment - this is not the same case

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to clarify exactly how the duplicate doesn't solve your problem. There are many near-duplicates on Stack Overflow so you'll probably just end up with a slightly different duplicate.

Comment: Something like this maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207292/bash-background-process-modify-global-variable

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I couldn't find a good duplicate though I don't doubt it exist. If anyone who came across this finds a matching duplicate or simply an answer, I would appreciate if you write here as a comment.