# How to wait until all background jobs initiated in a while loop have all finished a certain steps?

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to start a sequence of background job in a while loop in a bash script:

```
END=10
i=0;
while [ $i -lt $END ]
do
(SOME COMMAND;\
sleep 3;
SOME COMMAND 1;\
SOME COMMAND 2;\
SOME COMMAND 3;) &
i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

And outside this while loop I'd like to wait until all these 10 background job all finished `SOME COMMAND 1` and then proceed, so the psudo code is something like:

```
until [the number of process that finished SOME COMMAND 1 is greater or equal to $END];
do
sleep 0.5
done
```

What I tried to do is to add another counter like this:

```
true_started_cnt=0
END=10
i=0;
while [ $i -lt $END ]
do
(SOME COMMAND;\
sleep 3;
SOME COMMAND 1;\
true_started_cnt=`expr $true_started_cnt + 1`;\
SOME COMMAND 2;\
SOME COMMAND 3;) &
i=`expr $i + 1`
done

until [ $true_started_cnt -ge $END ]
do
echo "Waiting for initial period for all streams to finish"
sleep 0.5
done
```

But this seems not working, possibly because of simultaneous write of the same global var by multiple bg jobs. I wonder how to achieve my intention in this piece of code.

Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13209479/10400141), I'm also trying:

```
echo 1 >/dev/shm/foo

END=10
i=0;
while [ $i -lt $END ]
do
(SOME COMMAND;\
sleep 3;
SOME COMMAND 1;\
echo $(($(</dev/shm/foo)+1)) >/dev/shm/foo;\
SOME COMMAND 2;\
SOME COMMAND 3;) &
i=`expr $i + 1`
done

until [ $(echo $(</dev/shm/foo)) -ge $END ]
do
  echo "Waiting, true_started_cnt=$(echo $(</dev/shm/foo))"
  sleep 1
done
```

But still not working.

Comment: I guess you meant add `wait` outside the while loop? I think in that way I'm waiting for the whole bg job to finish, but my goal is just wait until they finish a sub-step, i.e. `SOME COMMAND 1`

Comment: Modifying variables in a subshell does not affect parent shell variables.

Comment: You also need to lock /dev/shm. In my opinion all of these aren't needed. You just need to record child PIDs and check each if they're still active or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be race condition in your last script as well, try this :

```
cp /dev/null /dev/shm/foo

END=10
for ((i=0; i<$END; i++)); do
    (
    echo SOME COMMAND;\
    sleep $((i+1));\
    echo $i SOME COMMAND 1;\
    echo $i >>/dev/shm/foo;\
    echo $i SOME COMMAND 2;\
    sleep $((i+1));\
    echo $i SOME COMMAND 3
    ) &
done

until [ $(wc -l /dev/shm/foo | awk '{print $1}') -ge $END ]
do
    echo "Waiting, /dev/shm/foo contains $(echo $(</dev/shm/foo))"
    sleep 1
done

echo "*********** All SOME COMMAND 1 finished"
wait
echo "Script finished"
```

Answer (score 0):

Recording progress isn't needed if all you want is to make sure all processes exit.

```
#!/bin/bash

END=10
pids=()

for (( i = 0; i < END; ++i )); do
    ( sleep "$(( RANDOM % 10 + 1 ))" ) &
    pids[$!]=$!
done


while [[ ${#pids[@]} -gt 0 ]]; do
    for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
        echo "Waiting for $pid to exit."
        wait "$pid"
        kill -s 0 "$pid" >/dev/null || unset 'pids[pid]'
    done

    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: I think in that way I'm waiting for the whole bg job to finish, but my goal is just wait until they finish a sub-step, i.e. SOME COMMAND 1

Answer (score 0):

You could use a FIFO queue to signal completion of a certain stage of jobs:

###### rendezvous.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -so errexit
shopt -so nounset

declare -ri job_count=5

# A FIFO queue where jobs will signal their completion.
mkfifo rendezvous

# Clean up FIFO queue on script exit.
trap EXIT EXIT; EXIT() {
  rm -f rendezvous
  trap  - EXIT      # Restore default interrupt handler.
  kill -s EXIT "$$" # Propagate interrupt.
}

# Wait until the known number of jobs have signaled their completion to the
# FIFO queue.
wait_rendezvous() {
  (
    local -i counter=0

    while read -r; do
      (( ++counter ))

      if (( counter == job_count )); then
        break
      fi
    done
  ) < rendezvous
}

# Signal completion to the FIFO queue.
show_at_rendezvous() {
  # For some reason, without the trailing ampersand some A jobs end up
  # dangling.
  echo "done" > rendezvous &
}

#
# Actual script logic starts below.
#
command_a() {
  local -i job_id=$1
  echo "Command A[$job_id]: start"
  sleep 5
  show_at_rendezvous
  echo "Command A[$job_id]: done"
}

command_b() {
  local -i job_id=$1
  echo "Command B[$job_id]: start"
  sleep 10
  echo "Command B[$job_id]: done"
}

# Launch jobs.
for i in $(seq 1 "$job_count"); do
  command_a "$i" &
  command_b "$i" &
done

# Wait for all A jobs to signal their completion.
wait_rendezvous
echo "All A commands done; now awaiting for B commands..."

# Wait for all remaining jobs to finish.
wait
echo "All B commands done."
```

#### Output

```
$ ./rendezvous.sh 
Command A[1]: start
Command B[1]: start
Command A[2]: start
Command B[2]: start
Command A[3]: start
Command B[3]: start
Command A[4]: start
Command B[4]: start
Command A[5]: start
Command B[5]: start
Command A[2]: done
Command A[1]: done
All A commands done; now awaiting for B commands...
Command A[5]: done
Command A[3]: done
Command A[4]: done
Command B[1]: done
Command B[2]: done
Command B[3]: done
Command B[4]: done
Command B[5]: done
All B commands done.
```

Comment: If we look at output, A3-5 ended after message "All A commands done".

Comment: @Philippe you're right, I should have added timestamps to the log. It's just a race condition in how the `echo` statements are executed, but the timeouts are respected.

Comment: I think it's because the `while` loop only runs once. Can you double check ?

Comment: @Philippe I've just checked by adding an echo statement of the counter value and it... varies :) I don't know much about the way Bash handles this kind of concurrency, but there are some race conditions in how output to stdout is processed.